# PhoneGap Geolocation is blocked in iOS10

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, ios10, w3c-geolocation

My Phonegap app leverages the (Cordova 3.8) webviews 'W3C Geolocation API'. Since upgrading from iOS 9.x to iOS 10 (beta) however, using

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(...)`

now returns an error:

[Access to geolocation was blocked over insecure connection to http://localhost. ERROR(2): Origin does not have permission to use Geolocation service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5yVr.png)

I do not currently use the [Cordova Whitelist Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist). Would using that help or is there a simpler fix?

Comment: I added the [geolocation plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation) instead of using the default Webview geolocation API.

Comment: If you are using the phonegap developer app to test, read my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/39768646/1351469. It's about Ionic, but the problem is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the [geolocation plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation) instead of using the default Webview geolocation API