# Ionic hybrid app geolocation blocked on iOS10

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation

Since iOS 10 came out and I updated my iPhone 6 `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` is not working.
Address and port: 192.168.0.16:8100 
Since geolocation API is considered as unsecured origin it would work only with SSL but can I do it in a Hybrid application where I don't know what will be the address on each phone?
I've already tried what's mentioned here: [Geolocation is blocked in iOS10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39409071/phonegap-geolocation-is-blocked-in-ios10)

- Editing in XCode was not helping
- Editing the Info.plist in text editor was not helping

I have Cordova White List plugin istalled and I'm using this not recommended wildcard in my config.xml: `<allow-navigation href="*"/>` .

It works fine on android and was working fine on iPhone 6 before the iOS update.

Comment: are you testing the app on a real device? are you using live reload option?

Comment: @jcesarmobile Yes I'm testing it on a real device and am using live reload.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you are using live reload, when you use live reload the app code is served from a local web server on your computer using `http://` protocol.

If you don't use live reload the code will be loaded from inside your app using `file://` protocol and geolocation will work.

Consider sending a bug report to ionic so they maybe can change the local server to serve the code through https

Comment: Thanks a lot @jcesarmobile! I'll check it in like 5 hours and if omitting live reload resolves my problem I'll accept your answers. Have a good day!

Comment: Omitting the live realad helped to avoid the error on the console log but the navigator still not going through. Well your answer was correct on the original question so I accept it but my code still not working on iOS 10 but it did work on the version before. Thanks

Comment: Did you install the geolocation plugin?

Comment: Well months ago I just copied the plugins js file. Now I added the plugin properly and it works well. God bless you man! Thanks